# moved symlink disappears from Windows Explorer

Tags: clearcase, symlink, windows-explorer

I'd like to change the structure of our source code inside ClearCase before using a custom script to export that to another SCM system. As the original code may still change slightly, I did this by symlinking the contents of the existing folders into the new structure.

Now the desired folder structure has changed and I need to move those symlinks (or start the whole process over, which is my fall-back strategy if no one can help me here). But after moving any symlinks (inside the same VOB in a dynamic view by the way), Windows Explorer does not show the elements at the new position. ClearCase Explorer does show them as expected, in the new location and tagged as a symbolic link; but they appearantly lost their target, as the option "Warp to target" in the context menu is greyed out.

Restarting the PC and un-/remounting the VOB all did nothing to better the situaton.

Can anyone tell me how this could happen, how to prevent this from happening again and possibly how I can restore the appearantly broken links?

Comment: Did you used `cleartool move` to move those symlinks (or a drag and drop within the ClearCase explorer?). Or did yo move them through an OS explorer?

Comment: I tried both Ctrl+X, Ctrk+V and Drag-Drop. The ClearCase online help did not give any special instructions when using these methods.

Comment: Yes, but did you tried those move (Ctrl+X, Ctrk+V and Drag-Drop) through a *ClearCase* explorer or a *Windows* Explorer (i.e. without using ClearCase directly)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems I didn't read your comment thoroughly enough :/ 
I moved them from within ClearCase Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target has itself changed, it seems normal than the [VOB symlinks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_vob_link.htm) loses their target, and that the "**Warp to Symlink Target**" contextual menu doesn't work.

Check that your symlink (used here [in a dynamic view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_mvfs/c_symlinks_dyn.htm)) is a soft link.
But if move the link *and* its target change, I think it is quicker to remove and recreate the symlink.

---

Actually, the [OP SvenS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887962/svens) mentions in the comments:

> the **target path of symlinks may be stored relative to the link**.
>   This seems to be the case, as I just moved them back to their previous location and the targets reappeared in windows Explorer.

Comment: Not the `target` has been moved, but the `link`. The original files are still in place, I only want to rearrange the links to them. On the matter of soft links: I followed the instructions in the help entry["To create a VOB symbolic link"](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_create_slink_vob.htm) to create the links.

Comment: But your answer nevertheless gave me the idea the target path of symlinks may be stored **relative to the link**. This seems to be the case, as I just moved them back to their previous location and the targets reappeared in windows Explorer. I'll post this as an answer and open a new question on how to properly move symlinks... Thanks for the thought!

Comment: Hmpft, too low rep to answer my own question yet, I'm gonna mark this one as accepted. And here's the follow-up question on [how to move symlinks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416800/how-to-move-symlink-keeping-the-target) for reference.

Comment: @SvenS: I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility